# Updating the document in aliased index collection

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to figure out if there a efficient way to update a document in aliased index collection .I create index with alias names .When i insert the document i index using the access-event-logs_writer alias (Which refers to the most recently created index ) However i some flows i need to update the document.

1. If i update the with access-event-logs_writer alias, it works if the
   document is in the current index . If the index rotation has
   occurred , then document i want update is in other index and update
   with access-event-logs_writer fails.
2. i update the with access-event-logs alias, it fails if there are
   more than 1 index with this alias name.

One option is to query and find the index in which the document resides and use that index name to update.Also , in this approach as i am getting the source document , i can update in memory and index again with same document id (no update / deletion).

Please let me know if there is a better way to handle this update?

Below is how my alias looks like.

```
curl http://localhost:9200/_alias
{

  "access-event-logs_2016-03-06t00:00:00-08:00": {
    "aliases": {
      "access-event-logs": {},
      "access-event-logs_writer": {}
    }
  },
  "access-event-logs_2016-03-04t00:00:00-08:00": {
    "aliases": {
      "access-event-logs": {}
    }
  },
   "access-event-logs_2016-03-05t00:00:00-08:00": {
    "aliases": {
      "access-event-logs": {}
    }
```

}

Comment: You seem to have a daily index rotation. Do you know what date the document pertains to when you need to update it? If yes, you can forge the index name and update it directly without needing to query it.

Comment: Daily index rotation is for testing purpose .. It will be changed to some other value and it not determine the index name while updating ..

Comment: Then you can proceed as you suggested.